# What can affect MD5 function result in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, md5

I am running 2 MySQL databases **in different servers**. One works as expected, the other is giving me trouble with the MD5 function.

`SELECT MD5(1);`

In the "good" database, the MD5 returned is `c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b`
In the other, the value returned is `6334636134323338613062393233383230646363353039613666373538343962`

------------- Versions ---------------

GOOD:

```
protocol_version         10
version                  5.5.8
version_comment          MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine  x86
version_compile_os       Win32
```

BAD:

```
protocol_version          10
version                   5.1.73-cll
version_comment           MySQL Community Server (GPLv2)
version_compile_machine   x86_64
version_compile_os        unknown-linux-gnu
```

Why?

Comment: What versions of MySQL are the different servers running?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @dognose, sorry I deleted my comment you replied to. I was saying I tested on 5.1.70 and 5.6.16 and I get the same result. The binary string thing is about the charset, not the value. It always returned a string of hex digits.

Comment: I don't know what the issue is, but this might help. It's the same value, but represented as UTF8 hex values (eg. 0x63 = 'c'): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Mysql 5.5 the return was a binary string. After 5.5 the string return is non-binary

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5

Comment: That documentation refers to the charset of the string, not the value of the string.

Comment: @BillKarwin so why is it then? You're the guru!

Comment: @igasparetto nice man, GOOD LUCK! I hope this solves it, although the guru says otherwise.

Comment: @Hituptony, The upgrade did it!. I should have read the doc as well. Thanks! ;-) The same issue happened for sha1(), in the case someone comes across the same problem. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha1

Comment: @igasparetto sweeeeeee

Comment: @igasparetto: Glad it worked - but actually Bill is right. The change is just about the charset. But you might have some "different" charsets in use, which will lead to wrong results because of wrong conversions going on... compare `SELECT MD5(CONVERT(1 using utf16));` vs `SELECT MD5(CONVERT(1 using utf8));` - Md5 hashes the BITS of the string - not the string. Different charsets, different bits -> different hash. And if you convert a different hash into a wrong target-charset - the outcome is heavily wrong.

Comment: Going back few steps, the problem started when the generated hash was not found in the follow select-where. For instance `SELECT id FROM test where MD5(id) = 'MD5_of_id'` was returning nothing. The MD5_of_id string was generated using `SELECT MD5(id) FROM test where id = 1`. The charset explanation is puzzling me a bit as both queries were executed at the same server.